# In Memory Buffer to store data in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, jms

I have a requirement to store data coming from UI into some place that can be processed later. Writing in DB or file is not an option because these will take time.
I need this operation to be asynchronous so that the person does not have to wait for the data to be processed.
JMS is an option but the Queue might get overloaded because the calls are thousands in number.
Is there a way I can write it into a temporary Map or something that can be used later. It need not be synchronized

Comment: Well, it's hard to salvage from the little information that you have, but either you write something yourself, or maybe look into a non-java solution such as redis.

Comment: "It need not be synchronized" is a *very* brave call if you're going to have two things accessing it at once. In any case, "thousands in number" is a quantity, not a rate. You should specify how much data per some time frame will be coming in. Without that, we're just guessing at workable solutions.

Comment: Data inflow is 500 rows per minute with each row having 10 columns of varchar.

Comment: How many users? Is the data represented by a single POJO or is it an object graph?

Comment: Data is in form of single POJO. It comes from various EJBs being used by a number of users

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the size of amount? If it is less amount of data, you can solve this by storing in session.

Comment: This is not a answer please ask question in comment section

Comment: Data inflow might be 500 rows in a minute. Table has 10 varchar columns.

Comment: Then create one pojo class( having 10 varchar columns as setter & getter) ... store each row in in single pojo object.. assign these objects to a List. Initialize a Thread at back-end and process these objects when list size become some fixed size or some fixed interval. I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

1) Use an embedded Database which is very fast so there won't be much overhead to it.
You can start with exploring [H2 database engine](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).
This is in-memory+open source. You just need to include a jar in your project.

If data is more, in a longer run synchronized map will 
have a performance overhead.
In case of unplanned Sever/application outage, the user entered data may get lost if you store it in a Map.

2) You can use [Guava CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) where you can expire an entry based on time or on maximum size of cache, if using third party library is allowed.

3) You can consider using [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) if option 1 and 2 doesn't look suitable to you.